# Can I override the title of an input type=text element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any possibility to override the title of an `<input type="text" title="blah" id="name"/>` HTML element with js or anything other technology? My goal is to change that title based on an if condition:

I've tried different ways. Some of them would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (name.length < 3) {
        $('#name').prop('title', 'New title');
    }
});
```

Or

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
if (name.length < 3) {
    document.getElementById('name').title = 'New Title';
}
```

None worked, until now. Thanks!

**LE**

This is the full example I use, but still it doesn't work as expected (initially: when the form isn't submitted, the title should be "blah", after the user presses the submit button, if the textbox length is less than 3, then the "New Title" should be displayed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" title="blah"/>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').submit(function(e) {
            if (changeNameTitle())
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting the form for invalid data
            }
        });

        changeNameTitle();
    });

    function changeNameTitle()
    {
        if ($('#name').val().length < 3) {
            $('#name').attr('title', 'New title');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I've tested it in Firefox 40.0, and in IE 11.

**LE2**
I finally found the response I want. Is based on Mihai's response (whom I'd like to thank).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" title="blah"/>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return changeNameTitle();">Go</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeNameTitle(){
        if ($('#name').val().length < 3) {
            $('#name').attr('title', 'New title');
            return true;
        } else if ($('#name').val().length >= 3) {
            $('#name').attr('title', 'Ok');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW `document.getElementById('#name')` take an id, so not `#` needed, also you mistape `#nume` for the last one

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's just a typo error.

Comment: In your first example: `title` is an attribute, not a property. In your second example: `id`s must be unique, hence that `.length` makes no sense (and is undefined for that matter`. Furthermore, inside the `if` you use `#nume` instead of `#name`. The `#` have to be dropped in vanilla JS' `getElementById()` anyways.

Comment: @Sirko Yeah, sorry for that. There are just typo errors. I'm feeling bad because I can't find any fix, and I'm hurrying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial question was wrong. If you want to change the title after pressing the button you must do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form button').click(function() {
        changeNameTitle();
    });

    changeNameTitle();
});

function changeNameTitle()
{
    if ($('#name').val().length < 3) {
        $('#name').attr('title', 'New title');
    }
}
```

or even better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        if (changeNameTitle()) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting the form for invalid data
        }
    });

    changeNameTitle();
});

function changeNameTitle()
{
    if ($('#name').val().length < 3) {
        $('#name').attr('title', 'New title');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Can you, please, check my update?

Comment: See my updated answer.. your first question was wrong as we didn't knew what you needed to do..

Comment: :( It doesn't work. If I use your updated code, the title is "blah" (when the page is loaded), and it stays the same no matter if at least 3 chars are present in the textbox.

Comment: Holly cow! I'm really so dumb that I can't copy a text, or this technology is f***ed up? For the good of human kind, it'll be better to be the first one! It doesn't work! It still stays as "blah" and it doesn't change as needed. I'm re-posting the entire html doc in the first post. Please have a look at it, maybe I'm using the wrong bs version, or the wrong jquery version? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just updated my answer.. there was a missing `{` in the code.. `if (changeNameTitle()) {`. Please note that you can use firebug to debug the js code.. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/yovh1ew5/ . It is working now

Comment: Great! But as you can see, the initial message (when the page is loaded is not "blah", but "New Title")... And to be more precise, this code is intended to validate a textbox. When the page is loaded, the title should be fe "blah". When the user inserts/or not something in the textbox, the title should change accordingly: is the length < 3? title="New Title"; is the length > 3, title="". Now I can certainly say that i can reach the limit of the Universe, than to resolve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`:

```
$('#name').attr('title', 'New title');
```